# How to fetch specific data from hash if there are multiple matches for the key?

Tags: ruby

I have a hash of arrays through which I need to fetch certain data from it by iterating with each key matching value from an another array. The below code is working if I have only one matching criteria and If am using multiple keys it is throwing an error. How can I fetch if there are multiple key matches?

Below is the code for the above problem:

```rb
class Sample
    def check_inspection_data
        data = [{"FL"=>"F", "IN"=>"?", "Circ-7"=>"HM562"}, {"FL"=>"...", "IN"=>"I", "Circ-7"=>"HM563"}, {"FL"=>"F", "IN"=>"O", "Circ-7"=>"HM564"}, {"FL"=>"F", "IN"=>"S", "Circ-7"=>"HM565"}]
        inspections = ['I', 'O', 'B', 'H', 'G', 'S']
        puts inspections.each { |i| data.find { |d| d['IN'] == i }.fetch('Circ-7') } --> But it throws an error
        # puts data.find { |d| d['IN'] == 'I' }.fetch('Circ-7') --> This is working
    end
end

sample = Sample.new
sample.check_inspection_data
```

Below is the error am getting for the above code:

```rb
NoMethodError: undefined method `fetch' for nil:NilClass
  block in check_inspection_data at sample.rb:5
                            each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1801
           check_inspection_data at sample.rb:5
                          <main> at sample.rb:10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `inspections` iteration reaches the element `B`, it results in `nil`, because there are no elements in `data` where the value of its key `IN` is `B`:

```
p [{"FL"=>"F", "IN"=>"?", "Circ-7"=>"HM562"},
   {"FL"=>"...", "IN"=>"I", "Circ-7"=>"HM563"},
   {"FL"=>"F", "IN"=>"O", "Circ-7"=>"HM564"},
   {"FL"=>"F", "IN"=>"S", "Circ-7"=>"HM565"}].find { |e| e['IN'] == 'B' }
# nil
```

Similar to any other element in `inspections` that doesn't exist as a key in `data`.

Alternatively you can get the common "IN" values between `inspections` and `data`, iterate over each element in `data` and push to an array the values of "Circ-7":

```
DATA = [{"FL"=>"F",   "IN"=>"?", "Circ-7"=>"HM562"},
        {"FL"=>"...", "IN"=>"I", "Circ-7"=>"HM563"},
        {"FL"=>"F",   "IN"=>"O", "Circ-7"=>"HM564"},
        {"FL"=>"F",   "IN"=>"S", "Circ-7"=>"HM565"}].freeze
INSPECTIONS = ['I', 'O', 'B', 'H', 'G', 'S'].freeze

def check_inspection_data
  common_in_values = DATA.map { |d| d['IN'] } & INSPECTIONS
  DATA.each_with_object([]) do |e, arr|
    next unless common_in_values.include?(e['IN'])

    arr << e['Circ-7']
  end
end

p check_inspection_data # ["HM563", "HM564", "HM565"]
```

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I have understood the above mentioned answer. But how to ignore nil values and get only matching data